# NSRange `replaceCharactersInRange` crashing app after backspace & entry of new character

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsrange

I have one textfield, & use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method to get value.

Here is my Code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSLog(@"Pressing : %@\n", string);
    NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];

    NSLog(@"length: %lu", (unsigned long)range.length);
    NSLog(@"location: %lu\n", (unsigned long)range.location);
    NSLog(@"before text: %@", textField.text);

    [text replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"After replacement , Text: %@\n\n", text);

    // My work..

    return YES;
}
```

I first add character 'T' to textfield, it works fine ..

```
2016-03-02 10:06:23.162 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] Pressing : T
2016-03-02 10:06:23.163 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] length: 0
2016-03-02 10:06:23.163 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] location: 0
2016-03-02 10:06:23.163 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] before text: 
2016-03-02 10:06:23.163 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] After replacement , Text: T
```

Then, I backspace it to remove character, that also works fine..

```
2016-03-02 10:06:30.979 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] Pressing : 
2016-03-02 10:06:30.980 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] length: 1
2016-03-02 10:06:30.980 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] location: 0
2016-03-02 10:06:30.980 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] before text: T
2016-03-02 10:06:30.981 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] After replacement , Text:
```

But, when I am going to add new character then, it crash on replaceString..

> Note: This time, Range Gives length 0 & location 1, while first time also when i am adding T to empty textfield, it gives length 0 as well as location 0.

```
2016-03-02 10:07:02.158 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] Pressing : T
2016-03-02 10:07:02.158 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] length: 0
2016-03-02 10:07:02.159 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] location: 1
2016-03-02 10:07:02.159 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] before text: 
2016-03-02 10:07:02.159 MyTextFieldApp[12006:4323645] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: Range or index out of bounds'
```

I can't detect where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is crashing because you are attempting to insert data at an invalid location in the `text` mutable string.

The second time you press 'T', the value of `text` (retrieved from `textField.text`) is an empty string (literally `@""`).  You then call `replaceCharactersInRange` passing a `location` of 1 and `length` 0.  When you call `replaceCharactersInRange` with a `length` of 0 you are effectively saying "insert string" at position `location`.  This function only replaces text when the `length` is greater than 0.

When your code tries to insert the letter 'T' at the index 1 it can't (the first and only valid index of an empty string is 0), so the program crashes.

Also, for what it's worth, your program shouldn't return a location of 1 and a length of 0 if the textField is empty.  There must be something else going on.  I wrote your sample program in Swift and got the following output:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 200, 20))
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        textField.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(textField)
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        print("range.length: \(range.length), range.location: \(range.location), text: '\(textField.text!)' string: '\(string)'")
        return true
    }
}
```

output:

```
range.length: 0, range.location: 0, text: '' string: 'T' // press T
range.length: 1, range.location: 0, text: 'T' string: '' // press backspace
range.length: 0, range.location: 0, text: '' string: 'T' // press T
```

As you can see, I see the expected range of 0,0 on the second insert of T.  An Objective-C program should behave similarly.

Comment: I don't know, something is wrong with your program or something else was typed in the field.  I wrote the exact same program just to sanity check that UITextField is doing the right thing and as you can see from my output the ranges I get are fine.